# How do you stream M4V video on the web without using Flash?

Tags: iphone, cross-platform, video-streaming, m4v

I'm building a web site that needs to stream video and be friendly for handheld devices (especially the iPhone). Some handhelds don't support Flash so I'm avoiding the use of a Flash player. How does Youtube stream its videos so that they play on both desktops and iPhones? I'm looking for a player, or multiple players, which can be somehow activated based on the user's device.

Your help and guidance are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The YouTube website and others use the HTML5 video tag for streaming playback on iPhones. It works like this:

```
<video  width="480" height="360" controls>
    <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="test.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

In Safari (Desktop as well as mobile) and Chrome, the h264-compressed test.mp4 file will be played. Firefox will play back test.ogv. For other videos, you should still have a flash video player as fallback. You can have all the format choosing and flash fallback done automatically using [HTML5Media](http://code.google.com/p/html5media/). You might also check out [SublimeVideo](http://jilion.com/sublime/video), which provides video player controls for the `<video>` tag.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, MrMage :) 
I didn't realize that Firefox could use the <video> tag; I thought it was only on Safari.

Comment: I know its bit late.But just wanted to ask.since I was facing problem to play m4v video in hero framework and mozilla browser.